# gson.toGson() doesn't invoke custom serialize method

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I have an abstract class and set of concrete classes.

```
class AbstractClass {
..
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
..
}
```

I have a Custom Adaptor which implements JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer

```
public class AbstractClassAdaptor implements JsonSerializer<AbstractClass>, JsonDeserializer<AbstractClass> {


@Override 
public JsonElement serialize(AbstractClass src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
  JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
  result.add("type", new JsonPrimitive(src.getClass().getSimpleName()));
  result.add("properties", context.serialize(src, src.getClass()));
  return result;
}
@Override
public AbstractClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

  JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
  String type = jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();
  JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("properties");
    try {
       return context.deserialize(element, Class.forName("com.myjson." + type));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
       throw new JsonParseException("Unknown element type: " + type, cnfe);
}

}
```

//TestBlock

```
Gson gson =  new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(AbstractClass.class, new AbstractClassAdaptor()).create();

AbstractClass obj = new ConcreteClass();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

The Serialize method in AbstractClassAdaptor is not being called. This is evident from the json output, which contains no trace of type and properties after serialization.

Comment: gson is object of com.google.gson.Gson

Comment: Google gson is an open source library to serialize and deserialize java objects to and from json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get this working (and the only one I used so far) is to pass the desired type to the `toJson` method. So

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj, AbstractClass.class);
```

will call your customized serializer in the `AbstractClassAdaptor`. Likewise you'll need to do so when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation for GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter()

> This registers the type specified and no other types: you must manually register related types! For example, applications registering boolean.class should also register Boolean.class.

So as you should use a builder patter to add all of the implementations of the AbstractClass class to make it work.

```
Set<Class<? extends AbstractClass>> classes = someComponentsScan (AbstractClass.class);
GsonBuilder builder =  new GsonBuilder();
for(Class<? extends AbstarctClass> clazz : classes){
   builder.registerTypeAdapter(clazz, new AbstractClassAdaptor());
}
Gson gson = builder.create();
```